# Amazon Ec2, DNS resolution issue with google DNS server(@8.8.8.8)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coreos, consul

I have launched an amazon ec2 instance with coreos image in us-west region.

Consul is using google DNS name server and is not working because its not able to resolve DNS using 8.8.8.8.

I did a dig using name server and got an error:

```html
dig @8.8.8.8

; <<>> DiG 9.10.2-P2 <<>> @8.8.8.8
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Can someone share some pointers on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up reconfiguring consul which was using google DNS name server.
I had to reconfigure it to use amazon name server "169.254.169.253".

Still not sure why the same setup worked on us-east but failed on us-west.